# Creating tag labels inside an editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is to create a front-end editable tagbox (editable div). Whenever a user types a word into that box and presses `,` this box will change that word into a colorful label. The problem I am having is:

1. User types the first word in, presses the comma key.
2. The word is then wrapped in `<a>` tags.
3. User types the second word in, presses the comma key.
4. Now I have to leave the first wrapped word as it is and take only the second word into consideration to wrap it into an `<a>` tag as well. It's extremely tricky to me, I have no idea how to leave the first `<a>` tag alone and select "free" words for wrapping. This also means wrapping more than one word into a single `<a>` tag whenever the user decides to put a two-word tag. It has to work with any number of tags.

Could you please point me in the right direction? I am trying to solve this with jQuery. I don't necessarily need the code itself, because I know how to write it, I just need to come up with the right algorithm in my brain.

Comment: It would be nice if you update your question with your current code and, if it is possible, a jsFiddle.

Comment: I know @kmsdev, I would love to do that, but I deleted my last code as it was completely ineffective. The problem is - I need to have a concept first before I write any code and in this question I asked for such concept, an algorithm that would allow me to write some code.

Comment: Depending on whether you keep the commas in the field after replacing or not, split the inner HTML of the editable content by comma and/or </a>.

Comment: @Lain - splitting by `</a>` is actually a great idea. I'm surprised that I haven't thought about that. Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @Pe-Ter: I do not think that it is worth an own answer, but if that is how it is done here, I could do it.

Comment: @Lain - sometimes weird problems have simple answers. I've seen people giving a few words worth of answer and those were accepted with no problems. If you wish to do it then I invite you.

Comment: @Pe-Ter: Okay, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, as requested :)

Depending on whether you keep the commas in the field after replacing or not, split the inner HTML of the editable content by comma and/or .

Comment: [...]and/or `</a>` :).

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
function wrapInLink(container){
  var link_text = $(container).text().split(',').slice(-1).pop(); // finding the string for replacing with anghor tag
  var html = $(container).html(); // getting the container html
  html = html.replace(link_text, "<a href='link_to_be_given'>" + link_text + "</a>"); // replacing the link text with anchor tag
  $(container).html(html); // replacing the container's html
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think one of the users has provided a very simple way to achieve the same thing. Nevertheless, thank you very much.